# jquery (this).next() statement not working... syntax issue?

Tags: jquery, html

Having trouble getting a .next() selector to work.  Thought it would be straightforward, but I'm clearing doing something wrong.

Here's the script (not working):

```
$('.ITEM').hover(function (){
    $(this).next('.ITEM_LINE').toggleClass('ITEM_LINE_ON');
    setTimeout(function() {$(this).next('.midline').toggleClass('educ_color')}, 200);
});
```

and the html it is based on:

```
<div class="timeline">
    <div class="segment" style="height:30px">
        <div class="educ">
            <div class="ITEM" >
                <p>High School</p>
                <div class="ITEM_LINE educ_color"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="center">
            <div class="midline"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

        ..(repeats)...

</div>
```

The idea being that these element will be repeated a number of times so I only want the jquery script effecting the current one hovered over.  I'm guessing the '.midline' div may need another approach, but this should be possible with the '.ITEM_LINE' at the very least.

Thanks  !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find) because you are looking for a descendant element, not the next sibling element

```
$(this).find('.ITEM_LINE').toggleClass('ITEM_LINE_ON');
```

Also you have a problem with the `setTimeout()` method, `this` inside the handler does not refer to the hovered element anymore, you can use a closure variable to solve it

```
$('.ITEM').hover(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.next('.ITEM_LINE').toggleClass('ITEM_LINE_ON');
    setTimeout(function () {
        $this.closest('.segment').find('.midline').toggleClass('educ_color')
    }, 200);
});
```